# How to distribute RDP certificates from ADCS to non-domain members?

Tags: active-directory, rdp, pki

I have a few hundred systems that are not AD-joined, for which I'd like to issue RDP certificates from an internal hierarchy (built with ADCS).
I can do it manually, by generating CSRs, then signing with ADCS CA, then installing certs - easy, but multiply by a hundred, every 2 years or so, and it doesn't look attractive anymore.

How should I automate it?

Comment: Add them to the domain or use a Mobile Device Management solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Certificate Enrollment Web Services](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7734.certificate-enrollment-web-services-in-active-directory-certificate-services.aspx). What you are describing sounds similar to [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2010/05/25/enabling-cep-and-ces-for-enrolling-non-domain-joined-computers-for-certificates/) but instead of having the users request the certificate as described in the 'Testing the configuration' section you would instead request the certificates via [PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Request-certificates-from-b6a07151) or some other scripted process.